# Написание нескольких функций для выборки данных или одной, как правильно?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, backend

Выбираю связанные данные из 4 таблиц, и задался вопросом: как правильно организовать функции для выборки данных? Много думал над этим, но во всех вариантах всплывают какие то нюансы:

Пример:

```
есть таблица А -> поля id, name, status_activity,
есть таблица Б -> поля id, id_таблицыА, prop1, prop2,
есть таблица C -> поля id, id_таблицыА, data,
есть таблица D -> поля id, id_таблицыА, data,
```

Хочу написать функцию которая внутри будет содержать SELECT на выборку данных.

Вот тут то у меня и загвоздка... можно написать 4 функции в каждой по SELECT и принимать они будут параметр: массив с id из таблицы А, чтобы подставить в условие IN. Такой способ не травится тем, что нужно писать целых 4 функции и плодить их + 4 запроса.

Еще вариант: написать одну функцию, и внутри через JOIN склеить эти 4 таблицы, а в параметры по прежнему передавать массив с id из таблицы А, чтобы подставить в условие IN. Но тут есть опять заморочка: к примеру если функцию будет называться getFullDataById(array[1,2,3]), то тогда как делать фильтр по данным, не писать же кучу функций и не называть же их ByName ByStatus и тд.

Самое адекватное решение приходящее в голову, это вторым параметром передавать в функцию массив с параметрами, ключем будет поле в бд, а значением, значение в бд, к примеру status => 1, далее клеить это в WHERE и получаем универсальную функцию с 1 запросом на выборку всех данных. Что здесь не нравится: придется перед каждым вызовом этой функции писать массив конфиг, что выбирать, ну или в параметрах значение по умолчанию вставлять пустой массив.

Как писать такие функции для работы с бд правильно, дабы не плодить функции, не плодить запросы к бд, и остаться гибким в формировании выборки? Благодарю!

Comment: а в чем проблема с "плодить функции"?

Comment: @Ипатьев В том, что 1. растет их кол-во и поддерживать их становится проблематично, 2. больше функций, больше запросов к бд, что плохо. 3 если делать фильтрацию, то к примеру у меня 30 полей из 4 таблиц, значит мне надо писать 30 функций? Тоже плохо.

Comment: я не понимаю, что такое "поддерживать проблематично". количество запросов к БД не зависит от количества функций. фильрацию по 30 полям нельзя сделать с помощью 30 функций, это можно сделать только одной

Comment: я бы сделал общую функцию getDataByFilters(), а в дополнение к ней - ById, ByStatus, ByName, для случаев, когда нужно фильтровать только по одному полю, которые будут использовать getDataByFilters. просто для удобства, потому что прочесть ByStatus гораздо проще, чем разбирать что там в фильтрах написано

Comment: Только разумеется эта функция должна быть безопасной, защищая как передаваемые данные, что очевидно, так и **имена полей**

Comment: https://github.com/peter-gribanov/clean-code-php/blob/ru/README.md - вообще рекомендую к прочтению